# Count click with python pyautogui

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pyautogui

Hello guys i m starting learning about pyautogui and with the code below i can locate if an image is on my screen and click on it and count it and print count.

```
import pyautogui
import time


    def main():
        print('BOT PROTOTIPO 1.0')
        time.sleep(5)
        tentativa = 0
        while True:
            if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ButtonTest.png'):
                x = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ButtonTest.png')
                print('ButtonTest clicked')
                pyautogui.click(x)
                time.sleep(3)
                tentativa += 1
                print(tentativa)
    main()
```

What i need now is if ButtonTest.png was clicked by the user mouse, count in a different variable.

Hope you help me.

Comment: What do u mean "count in a different variable?"

Comment: Secondly, Python doesnt use semicolon (;)

Comment: Hello @TroyD as you can see tentativa is storing "auto clicks" i d like to add a new variable to count clicks made by user on ButtonTest.png

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but you cannot count/detect the clicks using pyautogui. You have to use pynput. The documentation is easy to understand and also really easy to find.

Comment: The late response is because of my school projects and all the NCE Philippine High School Review that I do with my parents.